# Django-nodejs-ishoutjs-redis: IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: python, django, node.js, sqlite

My goal is to build a realtime notification app using Django(1.8.5). I am using django server, Nodejs as push server, ishout.js[nodejs+redis +express.js API]. So I installed them by following the instructions.

I have build the whole project, Kindly suggest how it can be fixed

Error:1) Now when I am doing "$ python manage.py shell" , I get this error http://pastebin.com/DnGjpYEn

Actually by mistake I entered wrong password in first attempt, username was correct but password parameter got wrong, Now can I reset that to avoid the error depicted in pastebin above. By any ways and means can I repeat that step in correct manner. Also, initially there was some warning message related to sqlite3 in ubuntu terminal, hence in response to that I used     "$ python manage.py migrate"

Code can be accessed at https://github.com/arunsingh/real_time_notification

Comment: The error says `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username`, which means every time you are trying to add a username **arun** which is already present

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, though I am unable to figure out how I can fix this issue, Any pointers how should I proceed to solve this problem.

Comment: `u = User(first_name="Arun",username='arun').save()` using this code you are trying to save the user which is already present, only get the user don't save it again.

Comment: ok got the point, however I think you have not read the whole problem statement, while setting up new sqlite3 superuser I entered some password, but while passing that parameter in "Interactive python shell" I entered wrong password. I am not able to relate all these work flows and hence getting no work around solutions.